# reading a file from the github action

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, github-actions

I'm trying to read a file which is located under github/workflow folder using the github action which is attached below but getting error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'po_NODE_START_PROCEDURE_V2.json'

[image]

[image]

```
name: Deploy Logic Apps

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [review_requested, labeled]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Read StartNode json
        id: package
        uses: juliangruber/read-file-action@v1
        with:
          path: ./po_NODE_START_PROCEDURE_V2.json

      - name: Echo po_NODE_START_PROCEDURE_V2.json
        run: echo "${{ steps.package.outputs.content }}"
```

Comment: why not put the file into git repo(besides .git) instead?

Comment: @LeiYang tried putting in repo but still the same error

Comment: please paste your github action yaml here(don't put as image)

Comment: @LeiYang added above

Comment: i don't see any git glone action. please search and add it.

Comment: this is private repo.. publicly we can't access

Comment: i mean in the yaml file there should be a git clone job. then you'll find that file.

Comment: perfect it works now!! BTW when i tried to print the content is is throwing syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Check out https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your code as a first step before running any script or action against your code.

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

See also [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#understanding-the-workflow-file)